# How in React Material UI align 2 buttons in a dilog corner with a space within

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying in my dialog in MUI to put 2 buttons on the bottom right of it, aligned and with space within. the outcome I would like to reach is as screenshot

[image: Desired result]

What I'm getting instead is as follows:

[image: Wrong result]

As you see the button are not very well positioned and I cannot made space within.

Also they should have same size.

I created this sandbox based on original code:

[CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-dialog-forked-ikt2e?file=/demo.js)

The original code looks like this:

```
<Dialog open={isOpen} fullWidth maxWidth="md">
        <DialogTitle className={classes.dialogTitle}>
          <FormattedMessage
            id="Candidate.selectClinicTitle"
            defaultMessage="Select a clinic"
          />
          <br />
          <FormattedMessage
            id="Candidate.currentSite"
            defaultMessage="Current site: "
          />
          {site.name} {site.city}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <AutocompletePlaces sites={sites} />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogContent>
          <MuiDataTable
            data={preparedSites}
            columns={columns}
            options={options}
            components={{
              Checkbox: props => (
                <CustomCheckbox
                  {...{ ...props, defaultsite: site, sites: preparedSites }}
                />
              ),
            }}
          />
        </DialogContent>

        <DialogActions style={{ justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
          <Grid justify="flex-end" container spacing={12}>
            {' '}
            <Grid item>
              <Button color="primary" variant="outlined" onClick={onClose}>
                <FormattedMessage id="Candidate.close" defaultMessage="Close" />
              </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Button
                color="primary"
                variant="contained"
                disabled={!selectedSite}
                onClick={onConfirmToggle}
              >
                <FormattedMessage
                  id="Candidate.saveClinic"
                  defaultMessage="Save clinic selection"
                />
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is using margin like [in this code snippet.](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-dialog-forked-20k9o?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 1):

there!. You need to override material ui classes for custom solution. I just reviewed your code. you need to customize this class.
.MuiGrid-item": {
margin: "0px 10px",

}

Material ui is giving you lot of way to customize its classes. Just do inspect element and find where class is applying and then go to override it.

Materail UI docs give you api about props and classes.

Happy Learning